# Date conversion in pyspark or sparksql

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently having a field with the below date format.

```
3/2/2021 18:48
```

I need to convert it to 2021-03-02. I tried taking a substring and converting to date format. But it is not providing the desired output. Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Can you please show the code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Below if you are using spark SQL:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('3/2/2021 18:48', 'M/d/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Same functions are available in Dataframe API as well:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#from_unixtime

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#unix_timestamp